# Django Memcached Pickling Error

Tags: python, django, memcached

I am fairly new to Django and i am trying to use the builtin cache system. I am using Django 1.4.

### My goal

In my view i want to cache a call to an external API. Therefore i want to use `cache.get()` and `cache.set()`.

### My approach

1) I installed pylibmc as well as python-memcached

2) In my settings i added:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        # i also tried 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache'
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

3) In my view i added:

```
myData = cache.get('myKey')
if not myData:
    myData = myApiCall()
    cache.set('myKey', myData)
```

4) myApiCall() is a method call of the lastfm library:

```
api_key = '12345678901234567890'
api = lastfm.Api(api_key)
user = api.get_user('aLastFmUser')
myData = user.top_artists # this is the relevant line
```

### The problem

I get this error message when i use the pylibmc cache backend:

```
cPickle.PicklingError
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'module'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.module failed
```

And this one when using the memcached cache backend:

```
TypeError
TypeError: can't pickle module objects
```

Apparently, the pickling/serialization goes wrong. What is happening here?

Comment: What does `myApiCall()` return? It looks like you are actually trying to store a function/module in the cache as opposed to a result of a call to a function

Comment: i updated my question. therefore it's not possible to store an object in the cache? is the only possibility to create a dict and put all relevant data in it, so that i can store this in the cache?

Comment: You should probably use `user.top_artists()` (notice the parenthesis)

Comment: now i get this error: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: (for the line `user.top_artists()`)

Comment: As I understand `top_artists` is a list of `Artist` objects. Do you really need to pickle these objects with all their attributes and methods? I think not, so extract only needed data (e.g. artist names and playcount) and cache it. If you still need to cache list of object, dive into api's code and find the problem. :-)

Comment: Thanks DrTyrsa, that might be it. Although i do not understand what the problem is when i want to pickle a list of objects. Is it something particular in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [comment of DrTyrsa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362656/django-memcached-pickling-error#comment13353833_10362656) i found the solution:

Pickling objects can lead to errors, therefore it's more reliable to extract the needed data to a list or dict.